# Is there a Spring boot code style enforce, linter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My project currently using Springboot, and I want to enforce code styles like eslint and prettier. How do I do this?
For example:

```java
@GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getJson(@RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<String> msisdn, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<LocalDate> startDate, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<LocalDate> endDate, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<BlockStatusEnum> status, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> pageSize, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> pageNumber) throws IOException {
```

I want to enforce it to

```java
@GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get(
            @RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<String> msisdn,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<LocalDate> startDate, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<LocalDate> endDate, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<BlockStatusEnum> status, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> pageSize, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> pageNumber)
            throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't import eslint as you do in Angular for example but descent IDEs as intelliJ you can configure to enforce some kind of style.

You can read more here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#delete-code-style-schemes